# Central Limit Theorem in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to prove CLT in matlab by comparing histogram for sum of three RV and normal distribution.

Here is my code:

```
clc;clear;
len = 50000;

%y0 : Exponential Distribution
lambda = 3;
y0=-log(rand(1,len))./lambda;


%y1 :  Rayleigh Distribution
mu = 0;
sig = 2;
var1 = mu + sig*randn(1,len);
var2 = mu + sig*randn(1,len);
t1 = var1 .^ 2;
t2 = var2 .^ 2;
y1 = sqrt(t1+t2);


% %y2: Normal Distribution
y2 =  randn(1,len);


%y3 : What result excpected to be:
mean0 = (sum(y0)+ sum(y1)+ sum(y2)) / (len * 3);%how do I calculate this?
var0 =  1;%how do I calculate this?
y3 = mean0 + var0*randn(1,len);
delta = 0.1;
x3 = min(y3):delta:max(y3);
figure('Name','Normal Distribution');
hist(y3,x3);


%Central Limit Theorem:
%what result is:
res = y0+y1+y2;
xn = min(res):delta:max(res);
figure('Name','Final Result');
hist(res,xn);
```

I have two main problems.

1. How can I calculate mean and variance for y3 (what result should be)
2. Is my code correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `y0`, `y1` and `y2` are row vectors, you have to do:

```
mean0 = mean([y0 y1 y2]);
variance0 = var([y0 y1 y2]);
```

When you create `[y0 y1 y2]` you are creating a big vector with all your previous samples in a single vector (As if they were samples form one single distribution).

Now just plug it into the functions you want (mean and variance) as showed above.

---

About the statistical part: I think you are getting some things wrong.
The Central Limit Theorem applies for the sum of variables **distributed according to a same distribution**. It can be indeed be any distribution D, but all variables must have that same distribution D. You are trying to sum different distributions.

The theorem says:

[image: CLT]

I've coded an example for variables distributed according to an exponential distribution.
Run it and you observe that when you increase N, the resulting distribution tends to the expected normal distribution. For N=1 you have your exponential distribution (very different from a normal distribution), but for N=100 you already have a distribution that is very close to the expected normal distribution (you can see how the mean and variance are basically the same now).

**CLT for Exponentials with N=1**
[image: Sum of Exponentials for N=1]

**CLT for Exponentials with N=3**
[image: Sum of Exponentials for N=3]

**CLT for Exponentials with N=10**
[image: Sum of Exponentials for N=10]

**CLT for Exponentials with N=100**
[image: Sum of Exponentials for N=100]

**The expected normal distribution (convergence distibution of CLT)**
[image: expected normal]

```
clc;clear;
len = 50000;
lambda = 3;

%yA : Exponential Distribution A
yA=-log(rand(1,len))./lambda;

%yB : Exponential Distribution B
yB=-log(rand(1,len))./lambda;

%yC : Exponential Distribution C
yC=-log(rand(1,len))./lambda;

%yD : Exponential Distribution D
yD=-log(rand(1,len))./lambda;

%yE : Exponential Distribution E
yE=-log(rand(1,len))./lambda;

%yF : Exponential Distribution F
yF=-log(rand(1,len))./lambda;

%yG : Exponential Distribution G
yG=-log(rand(1,len))./lambda;

%yH : Exponential Distribution H
yH=-log(rand(1,len))./lambda;

%yI : Exponential Distribution I
yI=-log(rand(1,len))./lambda;

%yJ : Exponential Distribution J
yJ=-log(rand(1,len))./lambda;


%y1 : What result you expect it to be (centred Gaussian with same variation as exponential):
mean0 = 0;
var0 =  var(yA);
y1 = mean0 + sqrt(var0)*randn(1,len);
delta = 0.01;
x1 = min(y1):delta:max(y1);
figure('Name','Normal Distribution (Expected)');
hist(y1,x1);


%Central Limit Theorem:
%what result is:
res1 = (((yA)/1) - mean(yA))*sqrt(1);
res2 = (((yA+yB)/2) - mean(yA))*sqrt(2);
res3 = (((yA+yB+yC)/3) - mean(yA))*sqrt(3);
res4 = (((yA+yB+yC+yD)/4) - mean(yA))*sqrt(4);
res5 = (((yA+yB+yC+yD+yE)/5) - mean(yA))*sqrt(5);
res10 = (((yA+yB+yC+yD+yE+yF+yG+yH+yI+yJ)/10) - mean(yA))*sqrt(10);
delta = 0.01;
xn = min(res1):delta:max(res1);
figure('Name','Final Result for N=1');
hi  st(res1,xn);
xn = min(res2):delta:max(res2);
figure('Name','Final Result for N=2');
hist(res2,xn);
xn = min(res3):delta:max(res3);
figure('Name','Final Result for N=3');
hist(res3,xn);
xn = min(res4):delta:max(res4);
figure('Name','Final Result for N=4');
hist(res4,xn);
xn = min(res5):delta:max(res5);
figure('Name','Final Result for N=5');
hist(res5,xn);
xn = min(res10):delta:max(res10);
figure('Name','Final Result for N=10');
hist(res10,xn);

%for N = 100
y100=-log(rand(100,len))./lambda;
res100 = ((sum(y100)/100) - mean(yA))*sqrt(100);
xn = min(res100):delta:max(res100);
figure('Name','Final Result for N=100');
hist(res100,xn);
```

Comment: Well , After adding this , histogram for y3 and result have same shape but it seems variance and means are not same in y3 and result...

Comment: @Arashdn I've added a few comments and some extra code for you. Hope it makes things clearer for you

Comment: Nice answer. I just want to add the following: First, Matlab will never be a tool to demonstrate such things, it just shows you that it works for some dataset. This is not a proof, just a clue. Second, computer machines are finite and discrete machine, they can produce series that looks like random variable extracted from some distributions but they are not able to generate real random independent values, therefore IID hypothesis might not hold. Anyway Matlab or Octave are quite good tools, we just need to keep in mind what are their limitations.

Comment: Totally agree with you. The intention was not to demonstrate anything. It makes no sense to use numeric programming for mathematical demonstrations, but matlab is great to visualize results and get the intuition of things (such as the CLT).