# PDF and CDF plot for central limit theorem using Matlab

Tags: matlab, probability, cumulative-sum, probability-density, cdf

I am struggling to plot the PDF and CDF graphs of  where

> Sn=X1+X2+X3+....+Xn 
>    using central limit theorem where n = 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 10; 20; 40
>   I am taking Xi to be a uniform continuous random variable for values between (0,3).

```
Here is what i have done so far - 
close all
%different sizes of input X
%N=[1 5 10 50];
N = [1 2 3 4 5 10 20 40];

%interval (1,6) for random variables
a=0;
b=3;

%to store sum of differnet sizes of input
for i=1:length(N)
    %generates uniform random numbers in the interval
    X = a + (b-a).*rand(N(i),1);
    S=zeros(1,length(X));
    S=cumsum(X);
    cd=cdf('Uniform',S,0,3);
    plot(cd);
    hold on;
end
legend('n=1','n=2','n=3','n=4','n=5','n=10','n=20','n=40');
title('CDF PLOT')
figure;

for i=1:length(N)
%generates uniform random numbers in the interval
    X = a + (b-a).*rand(N(i),1);
    S=zeros(1,length(X));
    S=cumsum(X);
    cd=pdf('Uniform',S,0,3);
    plot(cd);
    hold on;
end
legend('n=1','n=2','n=3','n=4','n=5','n=10','n=20','n=40');
title('PDF PLOT')
```

My output is nowhere near what I am expecting any help is much appreciated.

Comment: That was a typo its actually " j=1:length(x)" instead of j=1.

Comment: Updated the code...

Comment: Fine! But some indentation would have been nice, too ;-)

Comment: Shoot too many edits my bad.

Comment: Okay, we have some working code. Now please explain what you expect. Furthermore, it is good practice to delete comments that are no longer valid (since an edit has superseeded them or similar).

Comment: HAve you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325458/central-limit-theorem-in-matlab)?

Comment: Your code is rather strange. You generate some random values, compute the cumulative sum, then compute the values of a uniform distribution at the obtained locations. I don't think it makes any sense. You should either compute N theoretical uniform distributions using [`makedist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/makedist.html), and add them together, then plot the result; or you should generate 1000 random values form a uniform distribution, N times, add them together to obtain 1000 random values from the sum of uniform distributions, and plot their histogram.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with vectorization using [`rand()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html) and [`cumsum()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html).

For example, the code below generates 40 replications of 10000 samples of a Uniform(0,3) distribution and stores in `X`.  To meet the [Central Limit Theorem (CLT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) assumptions, they are [independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables). Then [`cumsum()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) transforms this into 10000 copies of the `Sn = X1 + X2 + ...` where the first row is `n = 10000`copies of `Sn = X1`, the 5th row is `n` copies of `S_5 = X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5`.  The last row is `n` copies of `S_40`.

```
% MATLAB R2019a
% Setup
N = [1:5 10 20 40];    % values of n we are interested in
LB = 0;                % lowerbound for X ~ Uniform(LB,UB)
UB = 3;                % upperbound for X ~ Uniform(LB,UB)
n = 10000;             % Number of copies (samples) for each random variable

% Generate random variates
X = LB + (UB - LB)*rand(max(N),n);     % X ~ Uniform(LB,UB)    (i.i.d.)
Sn = cumsum(X);
```

You can see from the image that the `n = 2` case, the sum is indeed a Triangular(0,3,6) distribution. For the `n = 40` case, the sum is approximately Normally distributed (Gaussian) with mean 60 (`40*mean(X) = 40*1.5 = 60`). This shows the convergence in distribution for both the [probability density function (PDF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) and the [cumulative distribution function (CDF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function).

Note:  The CLT is often stated with convergence in distribution to a Normal distribution with zero mean as it has been shifted.  Shifting the results by subtracting `mean(Sn) = n*mean(X) = n*0.5*(LB+UB)` from `Sn` gets this done.

[image: Image showing convergence of Central Limit Theorem (CLT) as a sum converges in distribution]

Code below isn't the gold standard but it produced the image.

```
figure
s(11) = subplot(6,2,1)  % n = 1
    histogram(Sn(1,:),'Normalization','pdf')
    title(s(11),'n = 1')
s(12) = subplot(6,2,2)
    cdfplot(Sn(1,:))
    title(s(12),'n = 1') 
s(21) = subplot(6,2,3)   % n = 2
    histogram(Sn(2,:),'Normalization','pdf')
    title(s(21),'n = 2')
s(22) = subplot(6,2,4)
    cdfplot(Sn(2,:))
    title(s(22),'n = 2') 
s(31) = subplot(6,2,5)  % n = 5
    histogram(Sn(5,:),'Normalization','pdf')
    title(s(31),'n = 5')
s(32) = subplot(6,2,6)
    cdfplot(Sn(5,:))
    title(s(32),'n = 5') 
s(41) = subplot(6,2,7)  % n = 10
    histogram(Sn(10,:),'Normalization','pdf')
    title(s(41),'n = 10')
s(42) = subplot(6,2,8)
    cdfplot(Sn(10,:))
    title(s(42),'n = 10') 
s(51) = subplot(6,2,9)   % n = 20
    histogram(Sn(20,:),'Normalization','pdf')
    title(s(51),'n = 20')
s(52) = subplot(6,2,10)
    cdfplot(Sn(20,:))
    title(s(52),'n = 20') 
s(61) = subplot(6,2,11)   % n = 40
    histogram(Sn(40,:),'Normalization','pdf')
    title(s(61),'n = 40')
s(62) = subplot(6,2,12)
    cdfplot(Sn(40,:))
    title(s(62),'n = 40') 
sgtitle({'PDF (left) and CDF (right) for Sn with n \in \{1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 40\}';'note different axis scales'})

for tgt = [11:10:61 12:10:62]
    xlabel(s(tgt),'Sn')
    if rem(tgt,2) == 1
        ylabel(s(tgt),'pdf')
    else                           %  rem(tgt,2) == 0
        ylabel(s(tgt),'cdf')
    end
end
```

Key functions used for plot:  [`histogram`()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html) from base MATLAB and [`cdfplot`()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/cdfplot.html) from the Statistics toolbox. Note this could be done manually without requiring the Statistics toolbox with a few lines to obtain the cdf and then just calling [`plot()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html).

---

There was some concern in comments over the variance of `Sn`.

Note the variance of `Sn` is given by `(n/12)*(UB-LB)^2` (derivation below). Monte Carlo simulation shows our samples of `Sn` do have the correct variance; indeed, it converges to this as `n` gets larger.  Simply call `var(Sn(40,:))`.

```
% with n = 10000
var(Sn(40,:))         % var(S_40) = 30   (will vary slightly depending on random seed)
(40/12)*((UB-LB)^2)   % 29.9505
```

You can see the convergence is very good by *S*_40:

```
step = 0.01;
Domain = 40:step:80;

mu = 40*(LB+UB)/2;
sigma = sqrt((40/12)*((UB-LB)^2));

figure, hold on
histogram(Sn(40,:),'Normalization','pdf')
plot(Domain,normpdf(Domain,mu,sigma),'r-','LineWidth',1.4)
ylabel('pdf')
xlabel('S_n')
```

**Derivation of mean and variance for Sn:**

[image: Derivation of mean and variance for Sn]
<sub>For the expectation (mean), the second equality holds by linearity of expectation. The third equality holds since *X_i* are identically distributed.</sub>

---

The discrete version of this is [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59323687/8239061).

Comment: @SecretAgentMan, was wondering if you can please post the full code as you are generating the pdf and cdf plots which is missing in the above code.

Comment: @devadisha I've updated my answer to address your concern regarding the variance.