# PDF and CDF for Biased die using Matlab with Central Limit Theorem

Tags: matlab, probability, convergence, probability-distribution

I am trying to plot the PDF and CDF for a biased die roll for 10^4 samples using Central Limit Theorem.(CLT)

The die is biased or unfair where even sides are twice as likely as odd sides. Here is the diefaces = [1,3,2,4,6,2].What can I use in Matlab to find probability of an odd number in this case with CLT where Sn = X1 + X2 + ... + Xn , n = 40.

Here is what I have tried so far. The part that I am struggling with is passing the samples which in this case is 10^4 and n=40. Appreciate any help....

```
clear
% Roll the dice "numberOfRolls" times
numberOfRolls = 10000; % Number of times you roll the dice.
% Biased die with even sides twice as likely as a odd number
diefaces = [1,3,2,4,6,2];
n = 1; % Number of dice.
maxFaceValue = 6;
% Pick a random number from diefaces along with the number of rolls which
% is not working :(
x = diefaces(randperm(numel(diefaces),1),10000)


    S1 = cumsum(x)
    hist1= histogram(S1(1,:),'Normalization','pdf','EdgeColor', 'blue', 'FaceColor',  'blue')
```

Comment: This should get you on the right track: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914066/generate-random-number-with-given-probability-matlab

Comment: Is `Sn` the total number of pips (dots) on `n` rolls of a 6-sided die?  Is it the number of odd numbers in `n` rolls?  Can you define Sn?  Also, Sn = S1 + S2 + ... + Sn seems odd.  Did you mean Sn = X1 + X2 + ... + Xn?  Can you then define X_i (i = 1, 2,..., n)?   With clear definitions for these random variables, this question becomes very answerable.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan. (Thanks again) Just updated the question. I did mean Sn = X1 + X2 + .. + Xn. Xi representing a toss of an unfair 6-sided die with even
sides twice as likely as odd sides. Where Xi can take values of n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 20, and 40.

Comment: I get the 6 sides of the custom die and the definition of Sn.  You say Xi represents the toss of the die.  Is Xi the outcome (1,2,2,3,4,6)?  I don't see how Xi can be 1,2,3,4,5,10,20,and 40.  Can you clarify?  Please [edit] the question and explicitly define all random variables (answer these questions). I think we'll be able to proceed from there.

Comment: Let X1,X2,... be a sequence of iid RV with finite mean "mu" and finite variance sigma^2, and let Sn be the sum of the 1st n random variables in the sequence: Sn = X1 + X2 + ::: + Xn.                                                                                                                                 a) Let Xi the be a uniform continuous random variable taking values in the interval (0; 3). Consider n = 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 10; 20; 40 . b) Repeat part (a)  with Xi representing a toss of an unfair 6-sided die with even sides twice as likely as odd sides. Part (b) is what I am solving for.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan - Posted the actual question.

Comment: `diefaces = [1,3,2,4,6,2]`? Two 2 and no 5?

Comment: I read it as the die has faces `[1 2 3 4 5 6]` with probability  `[1/9 2/9 1/9 2/9 1/9 2/9]`. Though the approach I've taken is general enough to customize both the die faces and their probabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your die and obtain a valid [probability mass function (PMF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) for your custom die. You can verify the PMF by ensuring `sum(Prob)` equals 1. Note that a fair die is obtained by setting `RelChance` to `[1 1 1 1 1 1]`.

The die face probabilities below are `[1/9 2/9 1/9 2/9 1/9 2/9]`.

```
Die = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
RelChance = [1 2 1 2 1 2];            % Relative Chance
Prob = RelChance./sum(RelChance);     % probability mass function for die
```

You can use [`datasample()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/datasample.html) to simulate the outcome of rolling the die (requires Statistics toolbox). This is easy enough to hard code if absolutely necessary through several methods.

The code below reads *sample* `NumRolls` *many times from* `Die` *with the probability* `Prob(ii)` *representing the probability of* `Die(ii)`.

```
% MATLAB R2019a
NumRolls = 13;                        % Number of rolls 
Rolls = datasample(Die,NumRolls,'Weights',Prob);
```

Now, to use this to accomplish the stated goal. Similar to this post, create an array `X` that has the first row as realizations of X1, the second row realizations of X2, and so on. This doesn't have to be fancy.

And again, use [`cumsum()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) to get the cumulative sum along the columns. This means the first row is realizations from `S1=X1`, second row is realizations from `S2=X1+X2`, and the 40th row is empirical samples from `S40 = X1 + X2 + ... + X40`.

```
n_max = 40;
NumRolls = 10000;
X = zeros(n_max,NumRolls);
for n = 1:n_max
    X(n,:) = datasample(Die,NumRolls,'Weights',Prob);
end
Sn = cumsum(X);
```

**How to Plot?** At this point, since our variable names match the process, the remaining steps (plotting) are identical to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59295040/8239061) but with a few minor modifications. Since this is discrete (not continuous) data, I generated the plot below using the `'Normalization','probability'` option for [`histogram()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html). References to a [probability density function (PDF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) have been relabeled [probability mass function (PMF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) accordingly.

[image: Images showing the discrete analog to the Central Limit Theorem's convergence.]

---

Continuous version of the Central Limit Theorem is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59295040/8239061).

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the result of 10000 unfair die rolls with the probability for even sides twice as large as the odd sides like this.

First, let's define the odd and even sides of the die

```
odd = [1 3 5];
even = [2 4 6];
```

Draw 10000 uniformly distributed numbers.

```
r = rand(10000,1);
```

allocate some result variable

```
rolls = zeros(10000,1);
```

If you now split the random numbers at `1/3`, you have the probability for odd and even numbers with a ration of `1:2`. Since (I assume that) within the odd and even numbers, the probabilities are uniform (that is, the probability to get a 3 is the same as to get a 1 and so on), use uniform random numbers to assigne a respective value.

Use logical indexing

```
rolls(r>1/3) = even(randi(3,sum(r>1/3),1));
rolls(r<=1/3) = odd(randi(3,sum(r<=1/3),1));
```

Plot the result

```
histogram(rolls)
```

[image]

For the generation of the PDF and CDF with the CLT, use the [answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59293591/pdf-and-cdf-plot-for-central-limit-theorem-using-matlab), but use a distribution generated like above.

Comment: Good method, though the plot might be more intuitive if it was `histogram(rolls,'Normalization','probability')`